# How to deploy the best tuned model using sagemaker pipelines?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deployment, pipeline, amazon-sagemaker

I have trained an XGBoost model, finetuned it, evaluated it and registered it using aws sagemaker pipeline. Now I want to deploy the model. However, the location of the model artefact is saved as `Join` object because of which deployment is not working by `best_model.deploy(...)`. Any suggestions on how to deploy the best trained model.

```
tuning_step = TuningStep(name="HPTuning",
                        tuner=tuner_log,
                        inputs={
                            "train":...,
                            "validation":...
                        },
                        cache_config=cache_config)


best_model = Model(image_uri=image_uri, 
                  model_data=tuning_step.get_top_model_s3_uri(top_k=0,s3_bucket=model_bucket_key),
                  sagemaker_session=sm_session,
                  role=role,
                  predictor_cls=XGBoostPredictor)


register_step = RegisterModel(name="RegisterBestChurnModel",
                             estimator=xgb_estimator,
                             model_data=tuning_step.get_top_model_s3_uri(top_k=0, s3_bucket=model_bucket_key),
                             content_types=["text/csv"],
                             response_types=["test/csv"],
                             inference_instances=["ml.t2.medium", "ml.m5.large"],
                             transform_instances=["ml.m5.large"],
                             approval_status="Approved",
                             model_metrics=model_metrics)
```

The problem with `best_model.deploy(...)` is that `tuning_step.get_top_model_s3_uri(top_k=0,s3_bucket=model_bucket_key)` is a Join object. And deploy needs the s3 bucket location as a string. So that doesn't work.

I was also trying to deploy the registered model using

```
model_package_arn = register_step.properties.ModelPackageArn,
model = ModelPackage(role=role, 
                     model_package_arn=create_top_step.properties.ModelArn, 
                     sagemaker_session=session)
model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge')
```

which is giving me the error

```
...

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sagemaker/model.py in _create_sagemaker_model(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1532             container_def["Environment"] = self.env
   1533 
-> 1534         self._ensure_base_name_if_needed(model_package_name.split("/")[-1])
   1535         self._set_model_name_if_needed()
   1536 

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Which I also suspect arise for the same reason.

I followed this tutorial pretty much

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-pipelines/tabular/tuning-step/sagemaker-pipelines-tuning-step.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this -

1/ Once you have registered the best model from the Tuning Job in the Model Registry, run your model deployment code through the Lambda Step. [Here](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-script-mode/blob/master/hugging-face-lambda-step/sm-pipelines-hugging-face-lambda-step.ipynb) is an example of how to do that. Pass the output of the register step as the input of the Lambda step and call your model deployment code in the Lambda function.

2/ After your sagemaker pipeline executes and you have registered the model, use the registered model ARN from the Model Registry and call the deployment code. You can not use `register_step.properties.ModelPackageArn` outside the context of the Pipeline execution.

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar except with Sagemaker AutoML. Is there a way to include the AutoML training and deployment as steps within a Sagemaker Pipeline?

Comment: What if I want to call the definition function before running? This throws a can't pickle _thread.lock objects error.